# Select next occurence with IdeaVim in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, ideavim

The nifty `CTRL-G` on Mac, which selects the next occurence of a word, does not work when IdeaVim is activated. So for quite a while, I've just lived with disabling IdeaVim, every time that I want to do a multi-selection as such. But I use it more and more. Are there a work-around, to get it to work?

... Or can I do it VIM-style somehow?

---

**Concrete example**

If I have something like this:

```
$foo = 123
if( isset( $foo ) ){
  echo $foo;
} // if( isset( $foo ) ){
```

And I want to select all `$foo` and replace it with `$bar`.

**If I didn't use IdeaVim**, then I'd be able to select the first `$foo` and press `CTRL-G` 4 times (or press `CTRL-CMD-G` if I want to select all of them), and then write `$bar`.

... Currently, I just deactivate IdeaVim, and do it.

---

**Further notes**

I have tried and empty my `.ideavimrc`-file to ensure that it isn't something in there, that collides with it. And the result is the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can choose `IDE` handler for conflicting mapping if you want to execute idea action instead of vim's one.

[image]

Comment: Ahh! I wasn't aware of this. Thanks. However, - the multicursor-functionality isn't that nice, when using IdeaVim. If I do a multi-selection and press `SHIFT-i`, then I can type, and when I'm finished, then I can press escape and only then will it apply to all the places that had been selected. I know that it's a tall order, - but do you know of any fix to this (so it's possible to see the input as it's being typed, when using multi-cursor mode with IdeaVim)?

Comment: @Zeth Not using IdeaVim myself, but check comments in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-780 or other tickets -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM?q=multi%20caret

Comment: @Zeth yes, I was able to reproduce this bug. I can see that IdeaVim works like by http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#v_b_I (what is obviously wrong). You can create an issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM (or I will create it on Monday).